# sfGuardPlugin 4.0.2 breaks with sfPropelORMPlugin

Tags: symfony1, propel

A recent pull request requires 'isCrossRef: true' for the many to many list widgets to be generated in forms. Pull Request: https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/pull/90

The default forms will throw a fatal error when they try to set the labels for these list that aren't there anymore in the base classes.

Posting this up on SO in case someone else runs into this problem, because it took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is fixed since a week, see: https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/pull/136

Comment: hmm. maybe my submodules are boned, but I just reinstalled sfPropelORMPlugin as a submodule and my sfGuard forms are still wonky.  My git log shows the latest commit you were talking about.

Comment: On a side note, are phing and propel supposed to be checked out on (no branch) instead of master when you clone sfPropelORMPlugin? git submodules always confused me a little. Sorry.

Comment: If it doesn't work, comment on the issue #136 please. We need feedback :) Submodules are referenced by a commit, which means it's quite normal to be outside a branch.